# Update timestamps of files in windows using a text document for reference

Tags: parsing, powershell, timestamp

I need a way to update timestamps of files to the current date using a text document as a pointer to the files.

For example:

Directory A structure:

- A:\Level 1\Level 2\somefile1
- A:\Level 1\somefile2
- A:\Level 1\somefile3
- A:\somefile4

Text file (FilePointer.txt) contents:

- A:\Level 1\Level 2\somefile1
- A:\Level 1\somefile2
- A:\Level 1\somefile3
- A:\somefile4

Is there a way to parse the FilePointer.txt file to obtain file locations, and feed that to something that can update the timestamp for those files? Using powershell? Other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be pretty easy with PowerShell:

```
$timestamp = Get-Date # now
Get-Content filepointer.txt | Get-Item | Foreach {$_.LastWriteTime = $timestamp}
```

There's a bit simpler approach outlined [here](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/12/20/pscxtip-manipulating-file-attributes/).  It uses the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) Set-FileTime command e.g.:

```
Get-Content filepointer.txt | Get-Item | Set-FileTime
```

Or using aliases:

```
gc filepointer.txt | gi | touch
```

Comment: Upon further testing, files with "special" characters within the text seem to cause errors. accent marks, apostrophes, etc. Do I need to add single or double quotes somewhere?

Comment: Within my "filepointer.txt" file I have music file path's that contain apostrophes or accent marks due to different languages. These fail with "cannot find path" when attempting to update timestamps.

Comment: I have this in my test txt file `C:\users\keith\song's ``foo.txt` and I can't reproduce the error you're seeing.  Must be something related to the accent chars.

Comment: I have a windows command generating the filepointer.txt file (for /r %%a in (*) do echo %%a >> F:\Logs\filepointer.txt) It seems this command cannot process the accent marks in the file name, and instead omits the entire character. As a result, powershell correctly cannot find the path because it doesn't actually exist. I need another command to generate the filepointer.txt that will include accent marks or other special characters. Any thoughts?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem . -r | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach {$_.FullName} > F:\Logs\filepointer.txt`.  Or in V3, `gci . -r -file -name > F:\Logs\filepointer.txt`.

Comment: Again, thank you for all your help. That seemed to do the trick. All special characters are being written properly. This allows me to update the timestamps.